# Sharepoint 2010 on windows 7 home premium

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to work with sharepoint 2010.I have already installed sharepoint designer 2010 on my W7 home premium OS. But it is asking to have sharepoint foundation 2010 for server. When iam trying to install sharepoint foundation 2010 it shows error message that it is not supported on Home premium.But i have seen some posts where guys have already iinstalled it on windows7 Home premium. Can anyone please help me in installing sharepoint foundation 2010 on Windows7 Home premium,So that i could start away with sharepoint.

Thanks

Comment: NOTE: this question should be moved to the SharePoint Area of Stack Exchange... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 requires x64 so if your Windows 7 device is 32-bit you're out of luck.  If you have a 64-bit OS you can follow the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

However, If you have the HD space and enough RAM I would suggest creating a VM for this environment.  SharePoint "takes over" you machine in some ways.  I would highly suggest not installing it on your primary PC unless that machine is ONLY going to be a server.

You can DL a free copy of VMWare Player of Virtual Box to create the VM.